# Are there semivowels besides /w/ and /j/ and which are most common?

Tags: semivowels

In the languages I'm familiar with I can't think of any cases of semivowels other than the "w" and "y" sounds `/w/` and `/j/`. So are there any others and if so, which are most common beyond these two?

Comment: I think the nasals, liquids, and fricatives are also sometimes considered semi-vowels.

Comment: @Cerberus No, those are not semi-vowels although they can be syllabic nuclei. In fact, semi-vowels are the opposite, they're vowel (or vowel-like) sounds used on the edge of a syllable, so not acting as syllabic nuclei.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You listed:

- [j] which is a *[palatal approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_approximant)*, seen in words like **y**ou [ju:] (English);
- [w] which is a *[labio-velar approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labio-velar_approximant)*, seen in words like "**w**eep" [wi:p] (English). Following a comment request: It's a **labio-velar** because it's articulated with the *back part of the tongue raised toward the soft palate* (called also *"velum"* ⟶ *velar*) while *rounding the lips*.

There seem to be two others:

- [ɥ] which is a *[labio-palatal approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labio-palatal_approximant)*, seen in words like "月 **y**uè", [ɥœ˥˩] in Mandarin or, choosing a "closer" example, in "bonne n**ui**t", [bɔnnɥi] (French);
- [ɰ] which is a *[velar approximant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_approximant)*, seen in the Korean word for *doctor*, 의사 [ɰi.sä]

Comment: @Otavio Macedo: Thanks, your correction was actually needed in the other items too, so I added it. :)

Comment: The mixing of [ɰ] and [ɣ] is very confusing for me. I'm familiar with both Spanish and Korean and just don't know how to comprehend the Wikipedia articles.

Comment: You're right. I will change it to something else, so the mixing doesn't confuse people. You said you can't bring yourself to understand it completely: What is not clear?

Comment: Which symbol stands for which sound in Korean and which varities of Spanish. Is there supposedly the same sound in both but just often written with a different symbol? The Korean sound always seems a lot harder than the Spanish sound to me but I learned my Spanish in Mexico.

Comment: You correctly listed [ɰ] as a semivowel, but then gave a Spanish example with the non-semivowel sound [ɣ]. I think the confusion will clear up if you simply replace it with the Korean example [ɰi.sä], and remove the irrelevant digressions on the Korean writing system and the difference between a fricative and an approximant.

Comment: @AlekStorm: If you read the linked Wikipedia article, it actually states that `[ɣ]` is often used in place of `[ɰ]`, so it's not really Alenanno's fault. It's just not an easy to understand situation.

Comment: @hippietrail It is by no means Alenanno's fault; the Wikipedia article is flat-out wrong. Whether or not there is an alternation in Spanish, [ɣ] is not a semivowel. I suppose this is why wikis are editable; I'll go correct it now.

Comment: @hippietrail The article itself corrected me - the *symbol* [ɣ] is occasionally used for the approximant. Nevertheless, I'll update the symbol in the example to prevent this happening again.

Comment: Thanks Alek, I'm not enough of a linguist to know if these symbols are sometimes used freely or what the case is. I do know a lot of things are not as straightforward as expected once you start to get a little deeper.

Comment: @AlekStorm Thanks for your clarifying comments. Thinking back about it, it sounded indeed wrong.

Comment: @hippietrail Even linguists get confused sometimes :). The IPA is updated periodically with new symbols for sounds that have become "common enough" to warrant a special designation - the labiodental flap [ⱱ] is the most recent example. Before this happens, however, researchers describing the language will often reappropriate a different symbol to stand for the new sound, as long as there is no confusion *within the paper*. Often, their transcriptions are cited in other works without describing the notation, leading to a great deal of confusion.

Comment: @Alenanno: the "w" in English is a labial sound or at least it seems to me. Can you please elaborate a bit on the "Velar approximant" part of it?

Comment: @NikhilBellarykar Added a short explanation. :) If it's still unclear I can expand it.

Comment: @Alenanno got it, thanks. A kind of off-topic but related query: in the spirit of your explanation for "w", the "v" in English can be called as a "labio-dentalo-velar approximant", what say?

Comment: @NikhilBellarykar It's a [voiced labio-dental fricative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labiodental_fricative). The voiceless counterpart would be /f/.

Comment: @Alenanno got it, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @NikhilBellarykar Anytime! :)

Answer (score 6):

The behavior with semi-vowels has to do with their level of sonority. Typically, a vowel is the peak of sonority in a syllable. Semi-vowels are vowels which are not the peak of sonority because they precede and/or are followed by a more sonorous (open) vowel.

In principle, any vowel could become a semi-vowel if it preceded or was followed by something more sonorous (think less constriction) than it was, perhaps with the exception of low vowels (because they are the most sonorous sounds). In reality, I am not sure about the existence of mid semi-vowels, outside of the off-glide in falling diphthongs as in /aʊ/. Alek Storm listed the semi-vowels for the high vowels. Any other types of semi-vowels would probably not have distinctive symbols in the IPA because of their rarity.

It is also worth noting that it is not mandatory that a vowel become a glide if it is precedes or is followed by something more sonorous. A language might instead treat each vowel as the nucleus of its own syllable. It depends on the language's syllabification rules.

As a side note, vowels need not be the nucleus of a syllable: anything which is more sonorant than the surrounding segments can be. Languages vary on what types of segments they will allow to be syllabic nuclei, but Berber famously allows fricatives and stops: *tf.tkt* 'you sprained'.

Answer (score 5):

This ties into how one marks up diphthongs and polyphthongs. Strictly speaking you can add a non-syllabic marker (like the bow /̯̯̯/, or the more-open diacritic to closed vowels or the more-closed diacritic to an open vowel) to *any* vowel to produce a semi-vowel suitable for a diphthong, if how you define diphthong is a semivowel preceding or following a vowel.

As usual for IPA, frequent/common semivowels get their own symbols, which is why we have /j w ɥ ɰ/.

(Pet peeve: IPA isn't very good at showing diphthongs at a phonetic level, or rather, there seems to have been insuffcient interest in typological comparisons of diphthongs such that there is no agreed upon way of marking the difference between for instance English /aj/ in "hi" and Norwegian /ɑˑi̯/ "hai" or what have you.)

Comment: Hm, fascinating how different browsers show the ipa-symbols included above. YMMV

Comment: Given that the vowel space is continuous it's very difficult to have IPA symbols to precisely specify every location in, or movement through, that space. If you're comparing across languages then spectrograms or a plot of F1/F2 is best.

Comment: How does making a close vowel more open, or an open vowel more closed, produce a semivowel? And what is '...a semi-vowel suitable for a diphthong'? I don't think anyone defines a diphthong as a combination of semivowel and vowel. A diphthong is a monosyllabic vowel with two phonetic vowel targets. A semivowel is a vowel articulation used as a non-syllabic segment.

Comment: 1. I've seen /j/ defined as a more open /i/, presumably using the more open diacritic to show that it is an approximant. 2. Nobody agrees what a diphthong is, some define as I do, others not.

Comment: I believe Romanian is a case of a language which has many diphthongs and clearly distinguishes between them and semivowels, which it also has.

Comment: @kaleissin A more open [i] would be [ɩ] or [e]. A more open version of a vowel is another vowel. It is sometimes said that the [j] approximant has a narrower aperture than its equivalent vowel (a smaller aperture means less vowel-like). Do you have a ref for that definition of 'diphthong'? I think in linguistics it's pretty much agreed that diphthongs are a movement from one vowel target to another, occurring as a single syllabic nucleus. Or maybe the other way around is better: this kind of phone is given the name 'diphthong' in linguistics.

Comment: [ɩ] is no longer proper IPA. Btw, how would you mark something that is inbetween /i/ and /e/? The point is, not all people use the symbols the same way. There are several traditions in phonetic transcription, they use partly overlapping symbols and they use them differently. You *can't* say that X is always so-and-so without knowing what tradition/branch it comes from, that goes for plenty other sciences too.

Comment: @kaleissin: Nice comment but what do you mean by "[ɩ] is no longer proper IPA"?

Comment: @kaleissin Between [i] and [e], there's [ɪ]. For example, "BIT" is [bɪt].

Comment: @kaleissin Yes you're right, sorry, I didn't even notice myself that I had used lower-case [ɩ] instead of upper-case [ɪ], my mistake. Standard IPA (ie when not working within one of the traditions with its own transcription practices) is very strict about how the symbols are used.

To mark something between [i] and [e] I would use a lowering or raising mark on one of those symbols or maybe [ɪ], depending on the acoustic analysis. But that's got nothing to do with indicating a semivowel.

Comment: Aha I thought it might be a font issue and didn't realize it was a lowercase i instead of the IPA small capital ɪ.

Comment: @Alenanno what's between [i] and [ɪ]? The diacritics exist for a reason. You might never need something between /i/ and /ɪ/, that is: on the phone*m*ic level, but when you're comparing on a highly detailed phone*t*ic level you want as many ways to differentiate you can get.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia: Semivowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel) has a useful list, which adds some more details to Alennano's answer.  In addition to j, ɥ, ɰ, w, it says that some authors list ɹ and ɻ as semivowels.